# Layout not changed on rotation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen-support

I have 2 layouts with the same name located at layout and layout-land folders. However the landscape version sometimes isn't applied though the orientation change is detected in `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)`. Strange thing is it happens only in specific cases.
 My app workflow is : LoginActivity->TabActivity 
The problematic activity is in one of the tabs. When I leave login in landscape it is allright and behaves correctly in all cases. When I leave login in portrait the activity in one of the tabs doesn't use the correct layout when I rotate the screen.
Any idea what's wrong ? I can post some code if needed.

Comment: Show your AndroidManifest, it sounds like you have overridden the orientationChange so the system thinks you should be handling it yourself

Comment: assuming you havent locked up the activity in Portrait mode in the manifest file?

Comment: Checked it but no, in manifest the orientation isn't locked, otherwise it would never change the layout. But it changes when I leave login in landscape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `android:configChanges="orientation"` for your Activity in Androidmanifest.xml file....

Comment: Looks like it solved the problem, I am still confused that I have other activities completely similar and this problem doesn't occur. Do you have any idea why it happens only in one activity and the others work well without this line in the manifest ?